# Unable to find Minecraft city. Did I lose it forever?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently, I had to re-install a Minecraft server that is hosted remotely. I backed up the "world" folder to my computer before doing the reinstall. Now that the server has been reinstalled, I have copied the world folder back to the server and have been unable to find the massive city that I have built.

Is it gone forever? Or did I forget to back something up? Me and a team of 3 other players have been in creative mode searching the map for hours but have been unable to find anything. I have tried dynmap and essentials plugins to help aid with the search. I also made sure that the Minecraft config file was set to match the name of the world folder. The only difference that I see with the server installation is that this time it's running version 1.8.8. Before the re-installation, the server was running version 1.8.3, but I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Did you have the coordinates of things pre-reinstall? Because everything should be at the exact same coordinates, assuming everything was backed up and restored properly. At worst, if you didn't backup the player data, everyone would start at the default spawn location for the world (close-ish to x0,z0). If everything is not at whatever coordinates they used to be, then there are a few possibilities:

Comment: ***1)*** you backed up the world correctly, but did not properly place it in the re-installed server, or failed to properly configure the server to use said world and and are now exploring a new world without your structures. ***2)*** you backed up the wrong world files. You restored them properly on the new server, but it was not the right world to begin with, so your structures are not there.

Comment: Could you give information about the server software, a screenshot from the root folder or world folder depends on the server software (I want to take a look which folders exisit) and the config file?

Comment: If you built this near the world spawn, then try dying and respawn. You'll probably be near the city. Otherwise we can't answer anything about the world without having a world download.

Answer (score 2):

You could try downloading [McEdit](http://khroki.github.io/MCEdit-Unified/) (I reccomend a 1.3.x version as the 1.4.x versions have been crashing a lot for me) and opening the level.dat of the backup. Then, switch to chunk view with tab, and use right click to drag the world around, looking for anything irregular that might be your city. If you look at all the generated chunks and don't see anything, then you probably made a mistake during the backup process, or a mistake in putting it back, in which case I suggest ensuring that the world name in properties exactly matches the backup name.

Answer (score 0):

Being a server owner, I can completely understand. Now, there is two things that may have happened. Number one being, you could have downloaded a "blank copy" of your world. This has happened to me plenty of times. It is when your backup you download downloads the chunks, but fills them in with seed data upon first boot. Sadly, if this has happened, your world is gone. If you are going to update your server, I HIGHLY recommend that you use multiverse to make a secure clone. the `/mv clone WORLDNAME BACKUPWORLDNAME` command to fix this. Other than that, you might just be screwed. Sorry.